# Error installing scikitlearn

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to install scikit learn using

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

But it doesn't get installed. I tried to install numpy and scipy at first but I could not install those either :(

[image: terminal error description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root access on your machine and want to install the package system-wide you can just

```
sudo apt install python-sklearn
```

If you do not want that or if you do not have root access then read on (the example is for python3; works for python2 just the same):

You need to install a `virtualenv` first (as non-root user) and then use pip within that `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/venv
```

Now you can either activate that `venv` and install:

```
$ . /tmp/venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or directly call `pip` (with its full path):

```
/tmp/venv/bin/pip install -U scikit-learn
```

First, you may need to do:

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

If you use the interpreter in that virtualenv (inside an `activate`d shell or again with the complete path `/tmp/venv/bin/python3` you should be able to use the scikit-learn package).

`/tmp/venv/` is of course a stupid path to put the virtualenv; you'd usually have it somewhere in your `/home`.

Here are [the docs for virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) (which included in the standard python distribution).

Comment: Since the `python-scikits-learn` package is a transitional package, maybe use `python-sklearn` directly

Comment: It works ! @hiro It's just an access permission error as you mentioned at first. I didn't focus much on error :( I installed python-scikits-learn, now how can I install python-sklearn ?

Comment: @AM.Firnas i was wrong at the beginning; you do not need `python-scikits-learn` (but it does not hurt either); just try to install `$ sudo apt install python-sklearn`. good luck!

Comment: Ok.So no need to uninstall anything.I can just install again by "sudo apt install python-sklearn" this, right ?

Comment: @AM.Firnas just tried on my ubuntu 16.04. works!